# Pandas swap column names with column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
User Chat_People Talk_People Schedule_Time
1    first       second      third
2    second      third       first
```

I want to convert it to look like:

```
User First         Second       Third
1    Chat_People   Talk_People  Schedule_Time
2    Schedule_Time Chat_People  Talk_People
```

I tried doing:

```
df["First"] = df.apply((lambda x: col_name for col_name in ["Chat_People","Talk_People","Schedule_Time"] if x[col_name] == "first"), axis=1)
```

But am running into:

```
TypeError: cannot create 'generator' instances
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`melt` then `pivot`

```
out = df.melt('User').pivot('User','value','variable').reset_index()
out
value  User          first       second          third
0         1    Chat_People  Talk_People  Schedule_Time
1         2  Schedule_Time  Chat_People    Talk_People
```